# Transpose unequal excel columns to rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have received an Excel table with different number of items per category:

```
Category A   Category B   Category C
22           11           1
34           15           6
55           4            18
33
36
```

I'd like to turn this into:

```
Category     Item
Category A   22
Category A   34
Category A   55
Category A   33
Category A   36
Category B   11
Category B   15
[...]
```

What is a quick way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A macro will do that easily. The macro below will put the result in a new worksheet.

```
Sub TransposeStuff()
Dim lLastRow As Long, lColLoop As Long, lLastCol As Long
Dim shtOrg As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet

'turn off updates to speed up code execution
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


Set shtOrg = ActiveSheet
Set shtDest = Sheets.Add

shtDest.[a1] = "Category"
shtDest.[B1] = "Item"

lLastCol = shtOrg.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For lColLoop = 1 To lLastCol
    lLastRow = shtOrg.Cells(Rows.Count, lColLoop).End(xlUp).Row

    shtOrg.Range(shtOrg.Cells(2, lColLoop), shtOrg.Cells(lLastRow, lColLoop)).Copy
        shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset (1)

    shtDest.Range(shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1), _
                    shtDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(, -1)).Value = shtOrg.Cells(1, lColLoop)

Next lColLoop

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```